# Scala: AND conjunction in Lists

Tags: scala, functional-programming

So I have  `result: List[List[Int]] = (List(0,1), List(0,1), List(1))` and I want to get the numbers every element of the the list has in common (in this case 1) like a logical AND conjunction. How can I do that?

**Edit:** If an element is empty it should return an empty List because there are no values every element has in common

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: I think you want a Set instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Intuitive way**

In each sublist, filter out the elements that are contained in all sublists, then flatten and remove duplicated:

```
val result1 = list.flatMap(_.filter(e => list.forall(_.contains(e)))).toSet
```

**More efficient way**

Find the smallest sublist and pick out elements that are in each sublist:

```
val result2 = list.minBy(_.size).filter(e => list.forall(_.contains(e))).toSet
```

**Mathematical way**

Turn each sublist into a set and intersect them:

```
val result3 = list.map(_.toSet).reduce(_.intersect(_))
```

Comment: your third aproach fits the best, but I forgot to mention that in case of `List(List(0, 1, 2, 3), List())` an empty list has to be returned. Is it possible to do that with `intersect`?

Comment: Yes sure. Did you try it?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with the `intersect` [method](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.x/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#intersect(that:Seq[A]):List[A]):

```
def intersection(lists: List[List[Int]]): List[Int] = {
  lists.headOption match {
    case Some(head) =>
      lists.foldLeft(head)((acc, l) => acc.intersect(l))
    case None => Nil
}
```

The method may be more efficient if you use it with `Set` instead of `List`

Answer (score 1):

The difficulty here is to do the intersect on the empty element, in this case `Set.empty` . to avoid this and solve the problem more functionally we can do this

```
def uniqueElements(reults:List[List[Int]]):Set[Int] = {

  results match {
    case head1::head2::tail => head1.toSet intersect head2.toSet  intersect uniqueElements(tail)
    case head::Nil => head.toSet
    case Nil => Set.empty[Int]

  }
}
```